# International Targeting | Language > 'de-de' - no return tags (Google webmaster)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I have been using hreflang tag on my magento store.
I have basically four stores (having different language):

1. German
2. UK
3. French
4. US

After implementing all hreflang tag on all the pages of magento store still "International Targeting" on google "webmaster" still showing "1,270 Hreflang Tags with Errors" errors.

This is the site (https://www.trunki.com/de) for german store.

I think there is issue related with the crawl. I updated these urls on 05-may-2016 but errors are not recoverable.

Or anybody know how to crawl international targeting in google webmaster?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your errors is "no return tag" it means that one of your pages are not pointing back to the main page, for example

English page -> French page

The french page should return a URL for the English using the hreflang

French page -> English page

I check your website, the homepages are pointing to each other, maybe you have errors in the internal pages (categories/items) or even the search results pages.